# how to trim of all lines from string except the first

Tags: swift

How would I go about removing the second and third lines of the following example?

```
var testString: String = "Hello \n My \n Friend"
```

so it would print like this:

"Hello"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var firstLine = testString.componentsSeparatedByString("\n").first
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, much appreciated.

Comment: This is a very inefficient solution. It scans the entire string and creates an array of strings. All just so you can get the first one. It would be far more efficient to get the index of the first newline and then simply get the substring up to that index.